# How to check current DNS records with Amazon Route 53?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reverse-dns

I understand how records are created and deleted but I cannot figure out how to list all set DNS records with Amazon Route 53. I have checked the developer guide and cannot find anything on this. I want to know which records are currently in place/have been created. Does anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListResourceRecordSets` from the API; if you have more than 100 entries, you will need to make additional calls. Each request returns items starting from the first entry matching the name and type parameters specified. The returned response is in XML.

See:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/ and
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?ListingRRS.html